# MySQL: Updating id value which is PK in another table

Tags: mysql, sql, join, inner-join, crud

I have a table `table1` which has columns `o_id` as `PK`,  `ipaddress`, `b_id`

```
o_id    ip              b_id
9205    10.10.10.10     null
9206    10.10.10.11     null
9207    10.10.10.12     null
```

---more than 1000 rows

I have another table `table2` `id` which has columns as `PK`,  `ipaddress`, `b_id`, `env`

```
id      ip              o_id  env
18356   10.10.10.10     null  dev
18357   10.10.10.11     null  prod
18358   10.10.10.12     null  qa
```

---more than 1000 rows

Now, if `ipaddress` matches in both tables and `table2.env IN ('dev', 'qa')`, then I want to update both tables such that `table2.o_id = table1.o_id` and `table1.b_id = table2.id`

Here I want to update `o_id` in second table from the `o_id` in first table.
I also want to update `b_id` in first table from `id` in second table.

I have written below query.

```
update table1 t1
inner join table2 t2 on t1.ip = t2.ip 
set t1.b_id = t2.id,
     t2.o_id = t1.o_id
where t2.env IN ('dev', 'qa')
limit 2
```

I am getting an error `incorrect usage of limit`.

I want to update only 2 rows first and see how it looks? I dont want to update the whole table all at once

Comment: And what's the problem with your query? (Apart from the fact that limit is pretty much meaningless without an order by)

Comment: updated my question

Comment: I really-really wonder why people cannot search for a specific error message...

Answer (score 0):

You can't do exactly what you want.  MySQL does not allow `limit` with a join.  You can use a subquery to restrict the number of rows:

```
update table1 t1 inner join
       table2 t2
       on t1.ip = t2.ip join
       (select ip
        from table1 t1
        limit 2
       ) t1ip
       on t1.ip = t1ip.ip
    set t1.b_id = t2.id,
        t2.o_id = t1.o_id
where t2.env IN ('dev', 'qa')
```

Comment: I am getting an error `table db1.t1 doesn't exist`

Answer (score 0):

You can't use `Limit` directly in the update queries. You should try something like that;

```
update table1 set col1 = '' where b_id IN (
select t1.b_id table1 t1 from
inner join table2 t2 on t1.ip = t2.ip 
set t1.b_id = t2.id,
     t2.o_id = t1.o_id
where t2.env IN ('dev', 'qa')
limit 2)
```

Comment: Yes, you can use limit in update queries, just not with the multiple table syntax.

Comment: Thanks but I am not using `col1` anywhere.